# How do i get a user to open my react native app from a text message (basically i need to make share profile in my react native app)

Tags: react-native

```
## import ##
import {Share, Button } from 'react-native'
```

Function to share. This function need to have link to a page of this app which will be sent to another user, who can see the same page if the app is installed, and if it's not, then it must be redirected to play store.

```
 const onShare = async () => {
        try {
            const result = await Share.share({
                message:
                    'React Native | A framework for building native apps using React   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.test',
            });
            if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
                if (result.activityType) {
                    // shared with activity type of result.activityType
                } else {
                    // shared
                }
            } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
                // dismissed
            }
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error.message);
        }
    };
```

button:

```
<Button onPress={onShare} title="Share" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a feature to open the app from the link then we should have to implement the firebase dynamic-link library and use it in our app navigation to check whether we have received the link in our app then we have to set the initial route to open a specific screen otherwise fallback to play store link if app not installed the fallback will auto handled by the dynamic-link library.

checkout the doc.
https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage